# What's the meaning of "run" in this?

Tags: word-meaning

> While the company was dodging me, it was also monitoring me. At my request, a number of police officers had **run** my photo through the app. They soon received phone calls from company representatives asking if they were talking to the media

This is from a newspaper. I cannot find an appropriate meaning of "run" in the dictionaries. What's the meaning of this "run"? Would anybody tell me what I should refer to in a dictionary when I look "run" up in a dictionary?

Comment: It's similar to *I'll have to **run** your request **by** the boss* (***present / show*** it to the boss, so he can either endorse your decision, or tell you what to do). Using ***by*** normally implies a "conscious" higher authority with control over decisions, but for something like an app, you just "feed" it the data (***run / pass*** it ***through*** the app).

Comment: There are many ways that **run** can be used, I suggest [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run) meaning "**5** to cause to pass lightly or quickly over, along, or into something, example *Ran her eye down the list*". Another suggestion is in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/run) meaning "**6** Be in charge of; manage." In particular meaning "**6.3** Carry out (a test or procedure), example *The doctor will want to examine the patient and may run tests to make sure she is okay.* Similarly the usage "Run that [idea] past me again." The verb is transitive.

Comment: @WeatherVane I really appreciate your detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "run through" means essentially, "fed as input to acquire the results of (to see what came out)."